# Could not build module 'FBSDKShareKit'

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

I'm upgrading some pods, namely to support `ParseLiveQuery`. I'm now running into an error in one of my header files

> Could not build module 'FBSDKShareKit'

Also in my errors:

[image]

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.3'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_modular_headers!

workspace 'myApp'

target 'myApp' do
    pod 'ROGoogleTranslate'
    pod 'Parse', '1.16.0'
    pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils'
    pod 'ParseUI', '1.2.0'
    pod 'ParseLiveQuery'
    pod 'SocketRocket'
    pod 'Bolts', '1.9.0'
    pod 'Bolts-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift', :commit => 'e9baa72d04521c3b25ef4fa6fef12b340953ee02'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '7.3.3'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.28.0'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.28.0'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.28.0'
end
```

I've deleted derived data, cleaned, cleared out my Pods directory and Podfile.lock. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Edit: this is being caused by including `use_modular_headers!` which stems from my actions after seeing this error

> [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:
>
> The Swift pod `ParseLiveQuery` depends upon `Parse` and `Bolts`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

Comment: Please see my answer. Maybe it will help. https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/issues/214#issuecomment-424994684

Answer (score 9):

```
use_modular_headers!
```

Works for me